# JavaScript Audio object not working in Android API 19

Tags: javascript, android, api, cordova, audio

I have created an Android app from html5 and JavaScript using ionic/Cordova framework.  In there I create and play an audio object as:

```
var myAudio = new Audio("myfile.mp3") ;
myAudio.play();
```

If I install the generated apk on Android API 21, audio plays fine. If I install it on API 19 it doesn't play.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi did you install the cordova media plugin?

I did something like that in the past with cordova 4.0.0 (definitely worked on android 19 (4.4.2 to be accurate)):

```
        AckSound:function(){
        try{
            var pathMedia;
            if(device.platform ==='iOS'){
                pathMedia ='';  
            } else {
                pathMedia = app.getCordovaPath(); 
            }
            var snd =new Media(pathMedia+'mySound.mp3'); 


            // Update media position every second
            var mediaTimer = null;


            mediaDuration = snd.getDuration();
            console.log("mediaDuration is " + mediaDuration); 
            snd.play();

            if(mediaTimer==null){
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function () {
                        // get media position
                        snd.getCurrentPosition(
                            // success callback
                            function (position) {
                                if (position > 0) {
                                    console.log((position) + " sec");
                                } else {
                                    //if position isn t > 0, the file is over
                                    snd.stop();
                                    clearInterval(mediaTimer);
                                    mediaTimer = null;
                                    snd.release();
                                    delete snd;

                                }
                            },
                            // error callback
                            function (e) {
                                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            }
                            );
                }, 100);
            };



            delete snd;

    } catch(err){
        console.log("Error: in AudioManagement.AckSound(), Error is " + err);
    }
    console.log("AudioManagement.AckSound() stops");

    }


},
```

Here is a full example: https://github.com/nyluje/TestMediaPluginCordova

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more info. What is Acksound?

Comment: Or even better if you have a completed html and JavaScript code that you can share here?

Comment: @TJ1 AckSound is nothing (it was my own stuff at the time). Did you install the cordova - media - plugin, and use a Media([your file].mp3) object instead of Audio([your file].mp3)?

Comment: @nyluie yes I did, still no success. I think I need to tell my app to use cordova media plugin somewhere? If you have a complete code that would be very helpful.

Comment: @TJ1 I ve droped you a full example on github: https://github.com/nyluje/TestMediaPluginCordova, it works on android kitkat device (validated before delivery)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's great, yes it is working :-)

Comment: is it possible t play this audio in infinite loop? I searched a lot and didn't find something that works with your solution.

Comment: Sorry I don t know about running it in loop, but if you look at the first piece of code above, you see that you can get the duration, so maybe you could read it from the start again when duration is over.